# Multi-dimensional index array to get multiple rows

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

How do you use a multidimensional array of indices to get the rows from a multidimensional array please?

It's throwing an error about the shape when I try variations of using the index array to pull the rows.

```
import numpy as np

neibs = np.array([[  1.7117279052734375000000e+01,   1.7255817413330078125000e+01,
    1.7325582504272460937500e+01,   1.7325582504272460937500e+01,
    1.7255817413330078125000e+01,   2.2046510696411132812500e+01,
    2.2232553482055664062500e+01,   2.2325582504272460937500e+01,
    2.2325582504272460937500e+01,   2.2232553482055664062500e+01,
    2.4651163101196289062500e+01,   2.4883720397949218750000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.4883720397949218750000e+01,   2.4651163101196289062500e+01,
    2.4883720397949218750000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.4883720397949218750000e+01,
    2.4651163101196289062500e+01,   2.4883720397949218750000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.4883720397949218750000e+01],
 [  1.8334333419799804687500e+01,   1.8333333969116210937500e+01,
    1.8333333969116210937500e+01,   1.6000000000000000000000e+01,
    1.2333333015441894531250e+01,   2.3333333969116210937500e+01,
    2.3333333969116210937500e+01,   2.3333333969116210937500e+01,
    2.0333333969116210937500e+01,   1.5666666984558105468750e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.1666666030883789062500e+01,
    1.6666666030883789062500e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.1666666030883789062500e+01,   1.6666666030883789062500e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.1666666030883789062500e+01,
    1.6666666030883789062500e+01],
 [  1.6334333419799804687500e+01,   2.1000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.3333333969116210937500e+01,   2.3333333969116210937500e+01,
    2.3333333969116210937500e+01,   1.7500000000000000000000e+01,
    2.2500000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    1.7500000000000000000000e+01,   2.2500000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   1.7500000000000000000000e+01,
    2.2500000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    1.7500000000000000000000e+01,   2.2500000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01],
 [  2.5001003265380859375000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01],
 [  2.5000999450683593750000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.2500000000000000000000e+01,
    1.7500000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.2500000000000000000000e+01,   1.7500000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.2500000000000000000000e+01,
    1.7500000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.2500000000000000000000e+01,   1.7500000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.2500000000000000000000e+01,
    1.7500000000000000000000e+01],
 [  2.5000999450683593750000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01,   2.5000000000000000000000e+01,
    2.5000000000000000000000e+01]])

neibs = np.reshape(neibs, (2, 1, 3, 25))

print('data shape')
print(np.shape(neibs))

activity = np.sum(neibs, axis=3, keepdims=True)

print('activity')
print(np.shape(activity))
print(activity)

#Sort the neibs for each input, channel
indices = np.argsort(-activity, axis=2)
print('sorted indices')
print(indices)
print(np.shape(indices))

#Get the top 2 indices for each input, channel
top_indices = indices[:, :, :2]

print('top indices')
print(top_indices)
print(np.shape(top_indices))


#Works as anticipated until this point
#Trying to get only the top 2 neibs for each input, channel
#The output desired is shape (2, 1, 2, 25)
#Tried below and multiple variations but to no avail
top_neibs = neibs[top_indices]
print('top neibs')
print(top_neibs)
print(np.shape(top_neibs))
```

Comment: Your `top_indices` has indices of `2`, which you got from `argsort` and can't use to index into axes with a length of `2`, needs a min of length `3`.

Comment: Thank you.  The neibs shape that is having the indices applied has shape (2, 1, 3, 25) and the top_neibs shape is (2, 1, 2, 1) so it should fit within that to get the indices shouldn't it?  Can you please give an example of how to fix it?

Comment: By the way here's the output:
data shape
(2, 1, 3, 25)
activity
(2, 1, 3, 1)
[[[[ 570.69867325]
   [ 529.33433342]
   [ 567.33433533]]]


 [[[ 625.00100327]
   [ 575.00099945]
   [ 625.00099945]]]]
sorted indices
[[[[0]
   [2]
   [1]]]


 [[[0]
   [2]
   [1]]]]
(2, 1, 3, 1)
top indices
[[[[0]
   [2]]]


 [[[0]
   [2]]]]
(2, 1, 2, 1)

Comment: and the error:IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-029726d1a75d> in <module>()
    108 #Trying to get only the top 2 neibs for each input, channel
    109 #The output desired is shape (2, 1, 2, 25)
--> 110 top_neibs = neibs[top_indices]
    111 print('top neibs')
    112 print(top_neibs)

IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2